# keycloak managed password with federated users

Tags: passwords, keycloak, federation

Is it possible to manage the password by keycloak with federated users? I have users
federated from external database and currently also the password is being checked from the external database.

Is there a possibility to register a password in keycloak for the user just after that user is created in the external database and then federated to keycloak?

My motivation is having the built in password reset functionality of keycloak not building extra SPI code for this on federated users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not really clear from your question, but since you have federated users from an external database, I assume you have implemented your custom `UserStorageProvider`. You are also validating passwords against your external database. So, I assume you have also implemented `CredentialInputValidator` interface. If you have not implemented `CredentialInputUpdater`, I would assume what you are trying to achieve should work out of the box.

If you have implemented `CredentialInputUpdater`, you could try to do the following:
Within you implementation of `CredentialInputValidator.isvalid` first check if the user has a local password configured, e.g. like this

```java
keycloakSession.userCredentialManager().isConfiguredLocally(realm, user, credentialInput.getType())
```

- If this is the case (returns `true`), simply have `isValid` return `false`. In this case Keycloak should use other `CredentialInputValidator`s and check for the locally configured password.
- If this is not the case (returns `false`), do the password check against your external database. Iff the password is valid, silently migrate the password to Keycloak's local credential store. This could look something similar to this:

```java
CredentialProvider passwordProvider = keycloakSession.getProvider(CredentialProvider.class, PasswordCredentialProviderFactory.PROVIDER_ID);
if (passwordProvider instanceof CredentialInputUpdater) {
    ((CredentialInputUpdater) passwordProvider).updateCredential(realm, user, credentialInput);
}
```

Within `CredentialInputUpdater.updateCredential` make sure to update the local store in addition to the password in your database.

Now your user's passwords will be stored in Keycloak's local database / credential store and the built in password reset functionality should work as expected.

Comment: yes I have UserStorageProvider implemented .... your answer look interesting, I have implemented only CredentialInputValidator,  as I wanted the users being readonly .. the only exception to this rule is the passward.  Currently If I try to change the passward I receive ....
Uncaught server error: org.keycloak.storage.ReadOnlyException: user is read only for this update, ... your solution looks great ... if it works I will accept

Comment: I have UserStorageProvider and I am trying to check this condition -- keycloakSession.userCredentialManager().isConfiguredLocally(realm, user, credentialInput.getType())
 but it always gives blank value. I am using Keycloak 20. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a possibility to register a passward in keycloak for the user
> just after the user is created in external database and then federated
> to keycloak?

From the [Keycloak Documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_user-storage-federation) itself:

> By default, Keycloak will import users from LDAP into the local
> Keycloak user database. This copy of the user is either synchronized
> on demand, or through a periodic background task. **The single exception
> to this is the synchronization of passwords. Passwords are never
> imported.** Their validation is always delegated to the LDAP server. The
> benefits of this approach is that all Keycloak features will work as
> any extra per-user data that is needed can be stored locally. The
> downside of this approach is that each time that a specific user is
> queried for the first time, a corresponding Keycloak database insert
> is performed.